# Android - Closing a fullscreen ImageView that doesn't always uses its full size?

Tags: android, imageview

I have an app where an image is loaded and attached to [Chris Banes PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView). When I click the image it goes to a layout and creates a fullscreen layout, this is needed to hide other functionality on the layout where the image is.

The imageView is set to match_parent on width and height because if it is set to match_content you can't really pinch to zoom. Because of this there is a lot of room around the picture, which is a transparent imageView which is used when a user uses pinch to zoom in.

The problem lies in the expected behavior that if you click on the transparent part next to the image that the fullscreen layout closes. However that is the same imageView that the image needs to expand in.

Initially I searched and found

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

But because the imageView takes up the whole screen so the image can expand into it there really is no outside to touch.

Is there an easy solution here? Like initially having the imageView set to match_content but when you start zooming that it sets the new width/height to what it needs? Or is it possible to address that extra space that isn't used by the imageView and set a dialog.dismiss or something on that.
Or is it just not possible in my current setup.

xml code (there is more but that isn't relevant for my question)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/iv_map_full_screen"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/ll_container_close_button"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code from fragment

```
private void showDialogFullscreenMap() {

final Dialog alertDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_map_fullscreen, null, false);

ImageView ivFullScreen = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_map_full_screen);
ivFullScreen.setImageBitmap(mTempBitmap);
mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(ivFullScreen);
```

Comment: Show us some code, that block of text was rough to get through. Maybe also add a screenshot or two showing what you have and what you'd like. To address your final question, you can indeed dynamically change the height and width of a view after inflation.

Comment: Also, if the "extra space" is a view, you can implement an `OnClickListener` that closes and cleans up.

Comment: @MeetTitan I added the code. Also how do you set the OnClickListener only for the extra space in an imageView?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by extra space. Do you mean space in the parent that isn't occupied by the `ImageView`? Or space in the `ImageView` that is not occupied by the image? The former you'd want to set the callback of the parent. The latter is a little more complicated, but I'd resize the `ImageView` to the image size and set the parent callback.

Comment: @MeetTitan I already know how to acces the space that is not occupied by the ImageView (dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);). So I need to know about the space in the ImageView that is not occupied by the image.

Comment: set this `android:clickable="true"` on your `RelativeLayout` that is occupying the rest of the space and it should fix your issue.

Comment: @kha This does not seem to work. Most likely because I have set the imageView height/width to match_parent. Because when I pinch the extra space it zooms in even if I don't pinch exactly on the image. The reason I did this is because the image starts out small but can be enlarged by pinch/double tap.